# What input can I use for the system function time() that will make it return -1 (error condition)?

Tags: c, time, error-handling

I am trying to create some error handling code in C. I am having trouble finding an input that breaks the function:

```
time(time_t *tloc)
```

I want to simulate time() breaking so I can test my error handling code. Either the input I try passes without an error or the entire program crashes (segfault). One error I am trying to produce is when the calendar cannot be located. In this instance, time() would return -1 and set errno to 14 ("Bad address"). How could I force this outcome without the kernel segfaulting me?

Comment: There are no reliable ways to make the `time()` system call return an error.  The argument can be NULL legitimately.  If it is neither NULL nor an address that can be treated validly as a `time_t` then all bets are off; your program is as likely to crash as to get an error indication.

Comment: It's dubious to me why you're trying to test this but you can try casting a large integer to a `time_t*` like `(time_t*)0xA0000000`

Comment: What about simply doing `time_t fail(time_t *unused) { errno = EFAULT; return -1; }` and then `#define time fail`?  Or maybe `LD_PRELOAD` hackery.

Answer (score 0):

Because the libc `time()` *function* on a modern `x86` linux kernel is implemented using a `vdso` syscall (See `man 7 vdso`), we have to resort to some trickery.

With `vdso`, the kernel is never entered. This is done for high frequency, speed critical calls (like `time`, `gettimeofday`, etc). All activity takes place in userspace.  Hence, the segfault. The real [non-vdso] syscall *will* do checks and return the desired error codes.

We must use `syscall(SYS_time,...)` to force entry into the kernel's version of the syscall.

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int opt_t;

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    time_t tv;
    time_t *tp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 't':
            opt_t = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    tp = (time_t *) 0xC0000000;

    // this segfaults due to vdso
    if (opt_t) {
        printf("using time ...\n");
        tv = time(tp);
    }

    // this returns error code
    else {
        printf("using syscall ...\n");
        tv = syscall(SYS_time,tp);
    }

    printf("tv=%8.8lX errno=%d -- %s\n",tv,errno,strerror(errno));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to force the `time()` function to fail is to run the application on a system that does not have a RTC (Real Time Clock).  However such a system would also fail for almost everything else.

Comment: Such a platform would be more likely to not have a `time()` function at all.